# Emberjs Binding stop working when select multipe = true

Tags: ember.js

If the select is multipe=false, it works. If we change it to multiple=true, the bindings stop working.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/163/

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  selectedServiceFlavours:  Ember.computed.defaultTo('serviceFlavours.firstObject.myvalue'),

  serviceFlavours: function(){
    return [
      {name: "1 (1)", myvalue: "1"}, 
      {name: "2 (2)", myvalue: "2"}, 
      {name: "3 (3)", myvalue: "3"}
    ];
  }.property(),

});
```

And the select:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=serviceFlavours optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.myvalue" value=selectedServiceFlavours multiple=true }} selected: {{selectedServiceFlavours}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `value` property is not supported for multiple selects. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#property_value

Comment: Thanks, so I have to use selection, how can I keep the default selection whe the content changes? http://jsfiddle.net/taLgt1md/4/

Answer (score 0):

Since the value property is not supported for a multiple select, you must use the `selection` property as you did in your fiddle:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=serviceFlavours optionLabelPath="content.name"
optionValuePath="content.myvalue" selection=selectedServiceFlavours multiple=true}}
```

In order to get your selected option to return to default on content update you need to pass the correct parameter to your computed property, like this:

```
selectedServiceFlavours:  function () {
    return [this.get('serviceFlavours.firstObject')];
}.property('serviceFlavours')
```

This way Ember knows to update the `selectedServiceFlavour` when the `serviceFlavours` change.

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/taLgt1md/5/